# use Vendor from other project ?

Tags: go, govendor

I use other project (Origin) vendor dir for small app (because they use older version of libs and its not compatible with current ones).
But i get these errors:

```
argument to kclient.Namespaces().List                                                                                                                                                                           
[mangis@mj origin-goclient-example]$ go build                                                                                                                                                                  
# github.com/mangirdaz/origin-goclient-example                                                                                                                                                                 
./main.go:15: cannot use &flags (type *"github.com/mangirdaz/origin-goclient-example/vendor/github.com/spf13/pflag".FlagSet) as type *"github.com/openshift/origin/vendor/github.com/spf13/pflag".FlagSet in ar
gument to "github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/cmd/util/clientcmd".New                                                                                                                                             
./main.go:29: cannot use "github.com/mangirdaz/origin-goclient-example/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api".ListOptions literal (type "github.com/mangirdaz/origin-goclient-example/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/a
pi".ListOptions) as type "github.com/openshift/origin/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api".ListOptions in argument to osclient.Projects().List                                                                    
./main.go:37: cannot use "github.com/mangirdaz/origin-goclient-example/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api".ListOptions literal (type "github.com/mangirdaz/origin-goclient-example/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/a
pi".ListOptions) as type "github.com/openshift/origin/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api".ListOptions in argument to osclient.BuildConfigs("my-project").List                                                    
./main.go:45: cannot use "github.com/mangirdaz/origin-goclient-example/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api".ListOptions literal (type "github.com/mangirdaz/origin-goclient-example/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/a
pi".ListOptions) as type "github.com/openshift/origin/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api".ListOptions in argument to kclient.Pods("my-project").List                                                             
./main.go:56: cannot use "github.com/mangirdaz/origin-goclient-example/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api".ListOptions literal (type "github.com/mangirdaz/origin-goclient-example/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/a
pi".ListOptions) as type "github.com/openshift/origin/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api".ListOptions in argument to kclient.Namespaces().List
```

how to make govendor and "code" treat vendor dir properly? what I'm doing here wrong?

code example:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    flag "github.com/spf13/pflag"

    "github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/cmd/util/clientcmd"
    kapi "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api"
)

func main() {
    flags := flag.FlagSet{}
    factory := clientcmd.New(&flags)
...
```

and it complains on flags being used wrongly.

Comment: You have to put all deps in a single, top-level vendor directory. Imports from different paths have different types, which are the errors you are seeing.

Comment: So I have "other" project vendor directory, but looks like its being ignored.